# bind_param dynamically mysqli

Tags: php, oop, dynamic, mysqli, prepared-statement

I understand that:

```
call_user_func_array(array(&$stmt, 'bindparams'), $array_of_params);
```

is what I need to do it, but I'm stuck.

First off, I'd imagine they need the s and i still for each variable you're binding, and if so, I'm completely lost on how to actually do it. I had attempted at reading the variables with `is_int` and `is_string`, but it just wasn't working and was cutting off my actual variable value, and I'd need it to dynamically read if it's string or int at the least.

If anyone could give me some example or point me to a site with an example I'd appreciate it. I've searched Google but can't seem to find anything on it really, and I've been looking for a few days now...

I can supply my `MySQLi` class if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Alright example](http://www.devmorgan.com/blog/2009/03/27/dydl-part-3-dynamic-binding-with-mysqli-php/)
That was all I could really find. It didn't work preparing and binding the statements unless it was an array great than 1 value, so you have to work it around to check if the value you passed in $params is an array or not, unless I was completely wrong. Either way, I got it to work.